# Dreamweaver configurate text in one big line

Tags: html, configuration, line, dreamweaver, markup

Hello I am using dreamweaver for HTML and I have a question about the "markup" of dreamweaver. When I have lets say 1000 characters in a p tag dreamweaver "sorts" it and it gives it new lines while I just want those 1000 characters in one line. Example:

Dreamweaver:

```
<p>Blablablabla
   Blablablabla
   Blablablabla
   Blablablabla</p>
```

What I want (notepad++ does this aswell):

```
<p>BlablablablaBlablablablaBlablablablaBlablablabla</p>
```

I hope someone can help me out with this on how to configure this.

Comment: Are you sure DW actually adds line breaks? This sounds like a *display* setting to me. Does the HTML file contain the line breaks when you look at them in another editor?

Comment: Its only in the program, not while you look at it in the browser, notepad or notepad++ just use one big line but dreamweaver just displays it as in my example all I have to know is where I can edit this, i've tried to google it but I couldn't really find something mainly because I don't know how you should look this up, things like newline or indentation did not provide information I was looking for

Comment: The "Word wrap" option looks good: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7be0a.html

Comment: Legend, that worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the Word Wrap **OFF**. in the code toolbar

[image: Turn the Word Wrap off]